# Blocking requests coming from host A to host B nodejs

Tags: node.js, cross-domain

My nodejs httpserver (i'm not using express) is hosted in HOST A, domain: www.host-a.com and does this:

```
dispatcher.addListener("post", "/admin/insert_data", function(req, res) {
var body='';
 req.on('data', function(chunk) {
  body += chunk.toString();
});
req.on('end', function() {
  var parsedbody = require('querystring').parse(body);
  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/database1', function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500) ;
      return res.end('Database offline') ;
    }
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
    var col = db.collection('mycollection');
    col.insert(parsedbody, function() {
      db.close();
      var json = JSON.stringify({status: "0"});
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });   
      res.end(json);

  });
});
});  
});
```

The client side is the following:

```
    $("form[name='manage_notizie']").submit(function(e) {

    req="../admin/insert_data"
    var tmp_notizia = $( "input[name=notizia]" ).val();
    var tmp_id_notizia = $( "input[name=id_notizia]" ).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: req,
        type: "POST",
        data: {id_notizia:tmp_id_notizia, notizia:tmp_notizia},
        async: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            location.reload();
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert("Errore nel server")
        },
        cache: false,
        });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I know that by deafult, if I don't specify any access control allow origin, the server will respond only if the request arrives from itself (host a).

Now, for example if a request comes from www.host-b.com to www.host-a.com/insert_data, my server would not answer to the request (like I want) but it does the computing stuffs (which I don't want)

Am I missing something?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i just want to avoid that the server run the code if any requests coming from different sources than the server itself arrives, so the question would be how can i block them? Without allow origins the server simply don't respond. But it still execute the code in the function (connect to db, insert the data and closing db)